# Solving for the set of algebraic parameters given constraints within the domain of a function

Tags: problem-solving, applications

I have a real world physical problem where I'm trying to determine the set of all possible coefficients of a function given specific constraints on the domain. I've managed to formulate the problem in mathematical terms, but I'm at a loss on how to proceed solving such a problem, or even defining what field of mathematics (other than perhaps simple algebra) might be used to solve the problem.

So what approach would I use to solve the following problem?

[image]

My first thoughts are that I have two (conditional) equations in two unknowns ($K_1 and K_2$), but the equations are nonlinear.

Comment: The graph of the function you gave always goes through $(0,0)$. I am finding it hard to understand what you are trying to do. You have a function $y(x)=x(K_2x+K_1)$. Can you please describe the constraints on this function (in words)?

Comment: @smcc Sorry, bad drawing. Please see my edit.

Comment: @smcc sorry again. You are right

Comment: @smcc  yes. I hope so. {xmin, ymin} and {xmax, ymax} are fixed points; lower and upper bounds through which the function cannot have a smaller x or larger x, respectively. So I'm trying to determine all values of k1 and k2 where these constraints hold. Furthermore the curve is concave up ( K2 > 0).

Comment: I cannot make sense of "through which the function cannot have a smaller $x$ or larger $x$". The way you have drawn it, the graph of the function goes through the points $(x_{\min},y_{\min})$, $(x_{\max},y_{\max})$. Is that all you want?

Comment: @smcc no, the graph shows only one possible curve that goes through both the upper and lower bounds of x at ymax and ymin respectively. At ymin for example, the function could go through any x > xmin and at ymax, any x < xmax. So I'm asking is there a way to solve for the set of k1, k2 that gives me those bounded functions.

Comment: I think then you are asking for values of $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that the image of the interval $[x_{\min},x_{\max}]$ under the function $f$ given by $f(x)=k_2x^2+k_1x$ is a subset of the interval  $[y_{\min},y_{\max}]$. That is the points between $x_{\min}$ and $x_{\max}$ all get mapped to values between $y_{\min}$ and $y_{\max}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @smcc maybe so. But it's really the domain (x) in this case that's being held as the constraining interval. The solution I thing should be conditional equations of K1 and K2 in terms of the xmin, xmax, ymin ymax constants. See my comment to Doug M. Is this problem even tractable?

Comment: What do you mean by "maybe so"? If you cannot explain your problem clearly, you will find it hard to get the answer your want. You seem to be using mathematical terminology incorrectly, which does not help. (For example, the domain of a function is the set of values it is defined on, but you seem to be using it in a different way.)

Comment: @smcc really sorry, I'm not a mathematician. I'm an engineer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ be given by

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx$$
for all $x\geq 0$, where $a>0$ and $b\geq 0$.

---

If you want the image of $[x_0,x_1]$ to be a subset of $[y_0,y_1]$ then you need

$$f(x_0)=x_0^2a+x_0b\geq y_0, \tag{0}$$
$$f(x_1)=x_1^2a+x_1b\leq y_1.\tag{1}$$

Multiplying $(0)$ by $x_1$ and $(1)$ by $x_0$ and taking the difference gives

$$x_0x_1(x_1-x_0)a\leq x_0y_1-x_1y_0$$

so we need

$$a\leq \frac{x_0y_1-x_1y_0}{x_0x_1(x_1-x_0)}$$

Multiplying $(0)$ by $x_1^2$ and $(1)$ by $x_0^2$ and taking the difference gives

$$x_0x_1(x_0-x_1)b\leq x_0^2y_1-x_1^2y_0$$

so we need

$$b\geq -\frac{x_0^2y_1-x_1^2y_0}{x_0x_1(x_1-x_0)}$$

---

Let $X_i$ be the element mapped to $y_i$, i.e. $f(X_i)=y_i$. If you want the inverse image of $[y_0,y_1]$, i.e. $[X_0,X_1]$, to be a subset of $[x_0,x_1]$ then you want

$$x_0\leq X_0$$
$$x_1\geq X_1.$$

Since $f$ is increasing, these inequalities are equivalent to

$$ f(x_0)\leq f(X_0)=y_0$$
$$f(x_1)\geq f(X_1)=y_1.$$

i.e.

$$x_0^2a+x_0b\leq y_0 $$
$$x_1^2a+x_1b\geq y_1  $$

so just reverse the inequalities on $a$ and $b$ from the other case.

---

Note that it is not always possible to find such $a>0$ and $b\geq 0$. For example, if  $x_0y_1\leq x_1y_0$, then in the first case we would need $a\leq0$, but $a>0$. Similarly, if $x_0^2y_1>x_1^2y_0$, then in the second case we would need $b< 0$, but $b\geq 0$.

Comment: I follow down to the point where you take the difference of the two inequalities, but the resulting inequality I'm not following. How do you know its <= rather than >= ?

Comment: because y1 >= y0?

Comment: If I have inequalities $c\geq d$ and $C\leq D$, then these are equivalent to $-c\leq -d$ and $C\leq D$. Adding them, we see that the inequalities imply $C-c\leq D-d$. Basically that is all I did (apart from also multiplying each inequality by a positive number in order to use subtraction to eliminate a variable).

Comment: Thank you for explaining - I see now

Comment: After checking by coding and graphing I found an issue with the initial equations. So I edited your equations to constrain x rather than y. x has to be between xmin and xmax. While this solution works for the equality condition, it does not hold if  I pick say for example a value of a less than the expression shown. The resulting function may fall within the required interval of x at the lower bound, but go outside at the upper bound, and vice versa with b. The constraint a > 0 has to work into the solution, but I believe there has to be another constraint that couples the values of a and b..

Comment: .. in oher words if you pick an a value, it would have to affect b, and vice versa. I apologize if I haven't communicated, described the problem accurately. It's likely my fault.

Comment: So are you saying you want the inverse image of $[y_0,y_1]$ (using my notation) to be a subset of $[x_0,x_1]$? That is, do you want the set of points between $y_0$ and $y_1$ to be mapped from points between $x_0$ and $x_1$?

Comment: I believe so. That's why I originally expressed the inverse of the functions, but I agree it's allot easier to deal with polynomials than the square root functions. I think my changes reflect that, but there's a definite coupling between the choice of a and b that throws the function out of bounds. I believe there is a missing constraint I'm just not realizing.

Comment: Please see the edit. I now have answers for both cases.

Comment: That's the same result I arrived at, and what I had edited from your post. But it still doesn't fully solve the problem. The results show solutions for $a$ and $b$ each as inequalities strictly in terms of only $x_0$,$x_1$,$y_0$, and $y_1$. But take either of the two original inequalities and solve for either $a$ or $b$ and you see $a$ depends on the choice of $b$ and vice versa. I haven't tested it yet, but I think the solution is to use one of the results above, say the inequality for $a$, then choosing an $a$, solve for the constraint on $b$ using one of the two original equations.

Comment: The missing constraint has to be some dependence of $a$ on $b$ or vice versa. When that dependence is broken, the result only holds for the equality condition.

Comment: You must have some other constraints on the function $f$ in mind than the ones above for which I provided answers for. Either of those constraints (image of $[x_0,x_1]$ a subset of $[y_0,y_1]$; inverse image of $[y_0,y_1]$ a subset of $[x_0,x_1]$)  leads to two linear inequalities that we are able to solve for separate inequalities for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I guess it's one of those problems that's really hard to put down into words without allot of description, examples, etc. or else personal discussion. I believe your answer set me off in the right direction, I'm just failing to communicate the other constraint. But thanks.